# how to display on html page in another html page in angular 4

Tags: html, angular, typescript, binding

Hi i am working on Angular 4

what i want know is **how can we bind HTML page on `(click)` in another HTML page**

I have tried `*ng-if` and `<ng-template>` but it didn't worked for me

so i just used basic HTML and Bootstrap `tab-pane fade` and `data-toggle` for my menu

but i want to have individual HTML pages for below three menu item and want to bind those respective pages when i click on respective menu

**I want popup a Modal when i click on menu , but i have some common modals in another folder**

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs flex-column" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#myappdefinitions" data-toggle="tab">My app definitions</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#shared" data-toggle="tab">shared with me</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#others" data-toggle="tab">shared with others</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```html
<div id="apptab">
  <div class="row justify-content-between">
    <div class="tab-content col-7">
      <div class="row tab-pane fade show active" id="myappdefinitions">
        <p class="text-muted">You have one app definition</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row tab-pane fade" id="shared">
        <p class="text-muted">you are in shared apps</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row tab-pane fade" id="others">
        <p class="text-muted">you are in shared with others</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon search-img">
                <i class="fa fa-search img-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control search-box" (click)="filterDelayed()" placeholder="search">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are mixing angular 1 with angular

Comment: can you please give solution with angular 4 @Chellappan

Comment: you need routing related or simple thing show html page?

Comment: I think you didn't understood my question @KarnanMuthukumar  i want to show one html page inside another html if the condition is true or if i click on a button or link and as my project contains some common html pages and modals in a separate folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used **ngx-bootstrap**

u can see below link

[ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/getting-started)

**I can do this button and respective model are in same HTML page**

still i can't figure out how to bind them if they are in different HTML pages.

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  TemplateRef
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  Router
} from '@angular/router';
import {
  BsModalService
} from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import {
  BsModalRef
} from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal/bs-modal-ref.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-application-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './application-dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./application-dashboard.component.css']
})
export class ApplicationDashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  modalRef: BsModalRef;

  constructor(private router: Router, private modalservice: BsModalService) {}

  ngOnInit() {}
  createApp(template: TemplateRef < any > ) {
    this.modalRef = this.modalservice.show(template);
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="createApp(template)" translate="">Create App</button>
<ng-template #template>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h2>Create a new app definition</h2>
    <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="modalRef.hide()">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>You need to give a name for the new app definition and you may want to add a description at the same time.</p>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="newAppName">App definition name</label>
      <input ng-disabled="model.loading" type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" id="newAppName" ng-model="model.app.name" custom-keys="" enter-pressed="ok()" auto-focus="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="newAppKey">App definition key</label>
      <input ng-disabled="model.loading" type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" id="newAppKey" ng-model="model.app.key">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="newAppDescription">Description</label>
      <textarea ng-disabled="model.loading" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" id="newAppDescription" rows="5" ng-model="model.app.description"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <div class="pull-right">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default ng-binding" ng-click="cancel()" ng-disabled="model.loading">
          Cancel
        </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default ng-binding" ng-click="ok()" ng-disabled="model.loading || !model.app.name || model.app.name.length == 0 || !model.app.key || model.app.key.length == 0" disabled="disabled">
          Create new app definition
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="loading pull-right ng-hide" ng-show="model.loading">
      <div class="l1"></div>
      <div class="l2"></div>
      <div class="l2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Angular Material. It's a UI utility component library for Angualar.

In HTML file

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active"  data-toggle="tab" (click)="openSomeModal()">My app definitions</a>
</li>
```

in TS file

```
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material';
 ....
 public dialog;

 constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

     openSomeModal() {
         const data = {};
         const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(yourModalComponent, {
             data: data,
             width: '400px',
             panelClass: 'any-class',
         });
    }
.....
```

In your module you have to import material stuff.

Check this Angular Material reference [link](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview)

Comment: i want it using only basic angular things. i don't import any other. Thank you for your sugestion @MalinduSandaruwan

Answer (score 0):

You should create another component(let me call it *child*) and import it in its parent's component(in `.ts` file) and then call child's selector(tag) in parent's `.html` file and create whatever you want.